# New Zealand Primark Equivalent?

Tags: shopping, clothing, new-zealand, working-holiday

Soon I'll be going to New Zealand for a year and rather than taking lots of clothes I would like to buy cheap ones while there.

I've done a little research and I can't see that they have anything similar to Primark over there.

[Primark is a UK clothing shop chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primark) often described as providing "disposable fashion"/"fast fashion" - on trend designs (admittedly often of very short lifetimes) at very low costs - eg. tops costing £3 (~4.40USD) and dresses costing £8 (~11.60 USD). An outlet can be found in most towns.

Does anybody know of any cheap clothes shops like this?

Comment: It would probably be easier to answer if you _explain_ what "similar to Primark" means. From a quick web search, Primark seems to be an UK-based clothes retailer. I cannot imagine that NZ doesn't have clothes retailers too, but whether any of them are "similar" to the particular one you name will be difficult to answer except for someone with an intimate knowledge of both countries -- and even then it's probably a toss-up whether they can divine the particular kind of "similar" you're imagining.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think it's not too difficult to understand that "similar to Primark" means "fast fashion" - even if one has never been to a Primark. H&M, Uniqlo, and Zara are some of the better-known similar brands. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_fashion#List_of_fast_fashion_brands

Comment: @davidvc: I have no idea what "fast fashion" means either.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47395/discussion-on-question-by-kmil-new-zealand-primark-equivalent).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Primark, but in New Zealand you can find inexpensive clothing at The Warehouse, Kmart, possibly Farmers, and probably others.

In general, goods available in New Zealand will not be as cheap as you might be accustomed to. There are many reasons for this (not the least of which is NZ is a small, remote market), but it all adds up to higher prices.

The Warehouse can be found in most major towns in New Zealand.

Update 2017: There are now H&M stores in Auckland, Wellington, and Christchurch. Can’t promise they are cheap!

Comment: The 3 shops you mentioned are probably the closest equivalent to Primark in NZ

Comment: +1 for the warehouse, cheapest prices of the lot... Quality on the other hand...

Comment: @RemarkLima if 'like Primark' is what OP wants, quality will indeed suffer ;)

Answer (score 14):

I am a Brit that lives in NZ, and I can tell you there is nothing quite like Primark.

The closest would be The Warehouse or kMart, (Farmers is more expensive than both, but quality and range is larger).
However, these still aren't as cheap, the range is a lot smaller, (given that clothing is only a small part of what they offer) and the quality isn't the same.

In all honesty, whenever I have made a trip back to the UK I have actually stocked up on clothes from Primark, there really is no true comparison, I would suggest the you do the same if you can.

Comment: Having moved from UK to Australia at one time in my life, this is correct. OP is far better off buying clothes in the UK, if NZ is remotely as expensive as Aus was. I had friends who waited until visits to the US to go clothes shopping, even.

Answer (score 11):

As of today (March 17, 2016), there are no **H&M**, **Zara**, **Primark**, or **Uniqlo** stores in NZ.

There is one **Topshop**, though, at [203 Queen St, Auckland](http://www.topshop.com/en/tsuk/category/store-finder-1824332/home?territories=&address=auckland), and **H&M** [will be opening an Auckland location](http://www.stuff.co.nz/business/73000449/Fashion-giant-H-M-may-open-more-New-Zealand-stores-after-Sylvia-Park) in 2016, too.

Maybe the Google search for [[new zealand fast fashion chain]](https://www.google.com/search?q=new+zealand+fast+fashion+chain&oq=new+zealand+fast+fashion+chain&aqs=chrome..69i57.2725j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) will yield more useful information. You can also check Wikipedia's [list of fast fashion brands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_fashion#List_of_fast_fashion_brands) to identify similar types of store, and then consult individual chains' websites.

Comment: There's some very handy information in this post that I was not aware of, Thanks!

Comment: I would say that Topshop, H&M etc are "similar" to Hallensteins, Glassons, Jay Jays, Just Jeans.  Generally a step pricier than The Warehouse but good options, especially when there are sales, and usually better quality

Answer (score 2):

just on top of the great answers above (and yes, Kmart and The Warehouse have quality clothes at very affordable prices), I'd say you'll find Op Shops in just about all towns and cities throughout the country. Op Shops stock second hand clothes (among other items) at very cheap prices, and although being second hand, are still good quality and ideal if you're traveling on a budget.
You can also find $1,$2,$3 shops that, as the name suggests, stock just about everything under the sun you may need for only a couple of bucks. These shops are also pretty frequent in the majority of towns and city centers across the country. You may not find them online though...but some sites may list them in shopping directories etc.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've traveled to the UK three times and live in New Zealand and feel that the stores here cannot compete with what Primark offers: amazing clothes and prices. We do have K-Mart and the Warehouse, but they are not comparable to Primark in terms of styles and price.